# Should I buy 2 core sets of Star Wars: the card game LCG right from the start?

Tags: star-wars-lcg

I've read some posts on BGG stating that you can only make decent decks to play [Star Wars: the card game](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/103886/star-wars-the-card-game) if you purchase at least 2 core sets.

Also it seems that if you want decent decks for all 6 factions two copies of the Edge of Darkness expansion are also needed.

My question is how much buying only 1 copy of the core will affect my overall impression of the game comparing to a initial big purchase of 2 cores + 2 edge of darkness?

Will I like the game better with the big package or is it possible to play for a couple of weeks to feel the game and after that purchase more cards?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I think this question is a bit too opinion-based for our format. You can clearly go either way, and no one can definitively tell you which way you'll like more. You *might* be able to turn this into a good question for this site by giving some objective criteria and asking about that, but otherwise you'd probably get better responses on a forum, maybe BGG.

Comment: It's not *that* bad. See [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) for some tips about how to ask questions like this in order to get good answers.

Comment: @Shujaa. I believe I might have formatted the question leaving some room for doubts and personal opinions, but from my point of view it is very clear. There are a few games that are only worth playing with a certain expansion and there are games that while the expansions are nice and add value they don't change the flavor of the original game. I want to know if Star Wars LCG would seem either broken or incomplete, though hindering my experience, with only 1 copy of the core set. For the answer I got, it seems the game is playable and adding another core set might only improve and not fix it.

Comment: @shujaa Some games might have legitimate cause to be worried about this. Expansion or no expansion? Basic set or full set? Sometimes, one of the options is crap, overloading for a newbie, or problematic in some major way. If there aren't any concerns and any way to start is a decent way, a good answer saying so is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I bought into the game, I only purchased one of the Core Set (and the first Force Pack The Desolation of Hoth, but that is an aside...). I just wanted to try a new game. A few of the guys behind the counter at the hobby store mentioned more than one Core Set, but I just wanted a new game. I wasn't going to enter any major tournaments to start with.

The great thing about the Core Set is you get a lot of cards right away, and you get playable decks. Four of them to be exact (Rebel, Jedi, Sith, and Imperial). You get a taste of the other two factions (Smugglers and Spies, and Scum and Villainy), but those are really fleshed out with decks in the Edge of Darkness set (and yes, I eventually bought that too).

I generally have recommended to anyone getting into the game to start with those. Try it. See how you like it. Learn how it plays and how to build decks.

I have also bought the Force Packs as they have come out. Unlike the Core Set and the Deluxe Expansions, the Force Packs come with two of every objective set (except for the ones labeled "only one in a deck"). I have thought about purchasing an additional Core Set and an additional Edge of Darkness set to have doubles of certain cards. But I still haven't yet. Part of it is my budget. The other part is I purely play for fun with my wife and with my friends. I dont' play in cut throat tournaments. Now in my personal opinion, I think as more cards are released, the less likely it is that you *have* to have two of every big set. More releases, means more cards to choose from, which means more variation in player deck constructions. So though it may once have been more important to have two of sets (especially when that was all there was), I think that is now lessened.

Again, a lot of that is my opinion and personal experience, but that is what I would pitch to any new player.